# Push div out when sliding another in

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Right now I have a basic template built to allow me to toggle sliding 4 different divs into a frame

[here](http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/homesite/demo2.html) is the site - try clicking the eyes, nose, or forehead

as you can see a div slides into the frame but,

now I want to add the functionality to slide the center div out when one of the div's slide in (so if the top div slides in the div on the screen will slide down and if the left div slides in the screen will slide right, etc)

any way to make this happen? I think it would have a great effect with the transitioned background

thanks everyone

katie

Comment: I could probably play with that for a few hours... haha

Comment: So, by center div, you're referring to the div containing the entire face, right?

Comment: You might need a variable to keep track of the div currently visible. Then on each click, you just slide the currently visible div out, and the new div in.

Comment: Can you stick your code into Fiddler for us, please.  Cheers.

Comment: @victorkilo by center div i am referring to the div containing the entire face

Comment: i have never made a jsfiddle but here is my attempt - for some reason i cannot get it to function correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/EuCEG/

Comment: @katiebekell - I know exactly what to do to make this work, unfortunately I'm at work.  I can code it out tonight if that's not too late...

Comment: @victorkilo thats not too late at all i would really appreciate your help

Comment: @katiebekell - I completely forgot last night :O  I think I will build out the functionality in a jsfiddle; it seems like the page that you have up is being dismantled :P

Comment: haah yea sorry i can revert back if thats easier- i am trying to turn my sliced image into divs so i will validate w3 style thanks victor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is absolutely position your content div within a fixed center div.  This will allow you to move around your content div, relative to the center of the page.  I am using css-transitions to apply the slide effect.  So the sliding will only work in modern browsers, but it degrades nicely to outdated IE browsers.

**Here's the fiddle with a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WVPDH/263/**

You will obviously need to modify this code some to work with your page, but it shouldn't be all too difficult to do so.

I've posted the code below in case the fiddle link goes sour:

### HTML:

```
<div id="fullContainer">
    <div id="right">

    </div>
    <div id="left">

    </div>
    <div id="top">

    </div>
    <div id="bottom">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="centerContainer">
    <div id="relativeContainer">
        <div id="content">
            This is where your face should go.  Notice that I placed it within a centering div.  
            This will enable the face to be absolutely positioned, and allow for you to modify 
            it's position when the side-bars slide in.
            <div data-move="left">Open Left</div>
            <div data-move="right">Open Right</div>
            <div data-move="top">Open Top</div>
            <div data-move="bottom">Open Bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#centerContainer {
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
#relativeContainer {
    position:relative;
}
#fullContainer {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#content {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    top:-200px;
    left:-150px;
    background:#BADA55;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#content.right {
    left:-250px;
}
#content.left {
    left:-50px;
}
#content.bottom {
    top:-300px;
}
#content.top {
    top:-100px;
}

#content div {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
}
#left {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-125px;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#left.opened {
    left:0;
}

#right {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-125px;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    background:green;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#right.opened {
    right:0;
}

#top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:-125px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#top.opened {
    top:0;
}

#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:-125px;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#bottom.opened {
    bottom:0;
}
```

### JS:

```
function SlideOut(element){

    $(".opened").removeClass("opened");
    $("#"+element).addClass("opened");
    $("#content").removeClass().addClass(element);

}
$("#content div").click(function(){

    var move = $(this).data('move');

    SlideOut(move);

});
​
```

Comment: Awesome! I definitely want to see the finished product :)